# Display data in WPF Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am developing wpf application, in which i have listview control. I am very new to wpf. But managed to add some styles and display horizontal gridlines inside Listview as below,

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="IDBorderedCellTemplate">

                <Border BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0,5,0,1"

                BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" >

                    <TextBlock Foreground="MediumBlue" FontFamily="Calibri" Margin="3,0,0,2" Text=""
                />

                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>


 <ListView.View>

                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">

                    <!-- Product ID -->

                    <GridViewColumn



          CellTemplate="{StaticResource IDBorderedCellTemplate}">
```

Now my problem is i am uable to display items in listview when window is loaded, which is displaying only gridlines. As my requirement is i have a browse button which i browse files, these browsed files must be displayed in listview.

As in load event i am adding following lines of code,

```
    try
    {

        listviewitem = new ListViewItem();
        //displays only the filename in the listview
        listviewitem.Content = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_name);
        _listFiles.Items.Add(listviewitem);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
   }
```

This data is not displaying in listview after adding the gridview settings in xaml. Now its displays only gridlines.
Any suggesions/help is appreciable.

Regards
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose the ItemsSource of listview as ObservableCollection or BindingList 
     for dynamic/frequently changing data instead of using listviewItem.

XAML

```
  <ListView  Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding FileStore}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Files" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

C#

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
   public ObservableCollection<string> fileList= new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
       // Add files to fileList (ObservableCollection)  
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> FileStore
   {
      get { return fileList; }
   } 
  }
```

Can add items to ObservableCollection anywhere like browse button click or load.